# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element error using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

How to write selenium test automation for this html. At Below There are html,java code and error. I am doing Everthing but i don't click to comboBox.

html code

```
<div _model-c4 class="blenderFive yellow"> 
<input _model-c4 type="checkbox" id="control-model-m-1">
<label _model-c4 for="control-model-m-1" class>
 ::before
 <span _model-c4 class="ppd-1"> Bathroom</span>
 ::after
</label>
</div>
```

java-selenium code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(""));
WebElement temp20 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//quick-checkbox/div/div/label"));
temp20.click();
```

Error

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div/input[@id='control-model-m-1']"}
      (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '3.9.0', revision: '698b3178f0', time: '2018-02-05T14:56:13.134Z'
    System info: host: 'STJ8CG445050D', ip: '10.134.12.134', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.88, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: D:\Users\home\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:44210}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
    Session ID: r4413edasdafq313405d909cd123
    *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div/input[@id='control-model-m-1']}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:473)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
        at sampleTEST.expressTest.bundle(expressTest.java:131)
        at sampleTEST.expressTest.main(expressTest.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try search it by this Xpath:

```
$x("//input[contains(@id,'control-model-m-1')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the `<input>` tag associated with the element with text as **Bathroom** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='blenderFive yellow']//span[normalize-space()='Bathroom']//preceding::input[1]"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click element by javascript. This is code:

> JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
>
> je.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);